# parsing "She wasn't at her best, it has to be said."

Tags: parsing

A sentence from "extra examples" of item 4 on [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/say_1):
**(1)** *She wasn't at her best, it has to be said*.

I would like to parse this sentence.
Is "*it*" a personal or anticipatory pronoun?
What is the grammatical function of the clause "*She wasn't at her best*"?

---

First variant of parsing (1):
**(1a)** *It has to be said **she wasn't at her best***.
(1a) is (1) without topicalization ( = fronting).
(1a) is an example of extraposition.

If (1) came from (1a), then:
"*it*" in (1) is an anticipatory pronoun and
"*she wasn't at her best*" in (1) is an extraposed subject after fronting.

Is this parse of (1) correct?
If not, then why not?

---

Second variant of parsing (1):
**(1b)** ***That** she wasn't at her best, it has to be said*.
(1b) is (1) with "*that*".
(1b) is an example of apposition.

If (1) came from (1b), then:
"*it*" in (1) is a personal pronoun and
"*she wasn't at her best*" in (1) is an appositive to "*it*", devoid of "*that*".

Is this parse of (1) correct?
If not, then why not?

Comment: "it has to be said" can be viewed as an adverbial meaning "undeniably" or "unavoidably" (in which case it doesn't really have an internal structure), or it can be a literal statement that something literally must be said.

Comment: You're using "apposition/appositive" incorrectly. Apposition is two phrases, one after the other, usually noun phrases, that refer to the same thing in different ways, both having the same role in the sentence. Like: "*My sister **Margaret**, **the seamstress**, could help you with your curtains.*" Both "Margaret" and "the seamstress" are in apposition to "My sister". They don't have any other role in the sentence. A pronoun referring back to an antecedent isn't an appositive. Do you perhaps mean "antecedent"?

Comment: @gotube There is an example from [here](http://www.english-for-students.com/Appositive-Phrases.html) where an infinitive phrase is an appositive to a noun phrase: _Tashonda's goal in life, to become an occupational therapist, is within her grasp this year, at last_. That is, a phrase and its appositive can be very different from each other. Proceeding from this, why can't "_She wasn't at her best_" be an appositive to "_it_"? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii Appositives act very similarly to *relative clauses*. Your example sentence, for instance, could be rewritten: "*Tashonda's goal in life, **which is** to become an occupational therapist, is...*". Your sentence 1b cannot be so rewritten because "it" is the subject of another clause: *"*That she wasn't at her best, **which it**, has to be said.*"

Comment: @gotube As far as I understood, applying your algorithm, "_which is_" should be added to the clause "_That she wasn't at her best_" but not to "_it_". So the whole sentence is turning into "_Which is that she wasn't at her best, it has to be said._". Since it's grammatical, we can consider "_that she wasn't at her best_" as an appositive to "_it_". Did I apply your algorithm correctly? Thanks.

Comment: @Loviii Not at all. And that sentence is not grammatical. An appositive is a phrase which follows another phrase, modifying the first phrase by *defining it in a different way*, and *it has no other role in the sentence*. "It" does neither of those things, so it's not an appositive.